# difference between named macro arguments and __VA_ARGS__

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I've written some utility macros to make turning an `enum` value into a `std::string`:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

#define MY_map_entry_(name, value) {#value, name::value}
#define MY_map_2(name, v1, v2) MY_map_entry_(name, v1), MY_map_entry_(name, v2)
#define MY_map_3(name, v1, v2, v3) MY_map_entry_(name, v1), MY_map_2(name, v2, v3)
```

This works completely as-desired:

```
enum class rgb { red, green, blue };
static const std::map<std::string, rgb> string_to_rgb{ MY_map_3(rgb, red, green, blue) };
// { {"red", rgb::red}, {"green", rgb::green}, {"blue", rgb::blue} }
```

However, it starts to get a little tedious writing the macros; so I thought I'd try `__VA_ARGS__`

```
#define MY_map_4(name, v1, ...) MY_map_entry_(name, v1), MY_map_3(name, __VA_ARGS__)
```

With a use-case of

```
enum class cymk { cyan, yellow, magenta, black };
static const std::map<std::string, cymk> string_to_cymk{ MY_map_4(cymk, cyan, yellow, magenta, black) };
```

This doesn't work, a similar macro without `__VA_ARGS__` does

```
#define MY_map_4(name, v1, v2, v3, v4) MY_map_entry_(name, v1), MY_map_3(name, v2, v3, v4)
```

Is there a way to write `MY_map_4` using `__VA_ARGS__`?

(Of course, it would be nice to do this—or at least get close—without using *any* macros; but I don't think that's possible.)

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want is an X-macro instead of a variadic one:

```
#define ENUM_VAL(X) X
#define ENUM_TO_STRING(E, X) {E::X, #X}
#define STRING_TO_ENUM(E, X) {#X, E::X}

enum class rgb
{
#define RGB_VALS E(red), E(green), E(blue)
#define E(X) ENUM_VAL(X)
    RGB_VALS
#undef E
};

static const std::map<rgb, std::string> rgb_to_string
({
#define E(X) ENUM_TO_STRING(rgb, X)
    RGB_VALS
#undef E
});

static const std::map<std::string, rgb> string_to_rgb
({
#define E(X) STRING_TO_ENUM(rgb, X)
    RGB_VALS
#undef E
});

#undef RGB_VALS
```

The idea behind is: You define your enum values in a subordinate macro that uses helper macros to actually generate the code.

With the helper macros you exchange the behaviour of the subordinate macro and you get the desired results for the different contexts.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong about your macro. GCC and Clang accept it out of the box, and MSVC needs `/Zc:preprocessor` (which enables the standard-conformant preprocessor; the default preprocessor is buggy).

---

The macro can be improved to support unlimited enum size (that doesn't need to explicitly specified), and to declare both the enum and the array. Here's an example. (Requires C++20, and Clang additionally requires `-Wno-gnu-zero-variadic-macro-arguments`. MSVC requires `/Zc:preprocessor`.)

```
#define ENUM(name, seq) \
    enum class name { END(ENUM_DECL_A seq) }; \
    std::pair<std::string, name> CAT(name, _values)[] = { END(ENUM_ARR_A seq) };

#define END(...) END_(__VA_ARGS__)
#define END_(...) __VA_ARGS__##_END

#define CAT(x, y) CAT_(x, y)
#define CAT_(x, y) x##y

#define STR(...) STR_(__VA_ARGS__)
#define STR_(...) #__VA_ARGS__

#define ENUM_DECL_A(...) ENUM_DECL_BODY(__VA_ARGS__) ENUM_DECL_B
#define ENUM_DECL_B(...) ENUM_DECL_BODY(__VA_ARGS__) ENUM_DECL_A
#define ENUM_DECL_A_END
#define ENUM_DECL_B_END
#define ENUM_DECL_BODY(name, ...) name __VA_OPT__(= __VA_ARGS__),

#define ENUM_ARR_A(...) ENUM_ARR_BODY(__VA_ARGS__) ENUM_ARR_B
#define ENUM_ARR_B(...) ENUM_ARR_BODY(__VA_ARGS__) ENUM_ARR_A
#define ENUM_ARR_A_END
#define ENUM_ARR_B_END
#define ENUM_ARR_BODY(name, ...) STR(name),
```

Then, `ENUM(A, (x)(y,42)(z))` expands to:

```
enum class A
{
    x,
    y = 42,
    z,
};

std::pair<std::string, A> A_values[] = { "x", "y", "z", };
```

Comment: @JayBach The alternative is having different macro implementations for different compilers, which also sucks.